# Pointer to Pointer Segmentation Fault with malloc

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm using a Pointer to Pointer in my function, but it's not a 2d Array, it's just one string. I tried all kinds of combinations and still can't get it to work, how does this work?

```
int get_next_line(const int fd, char **line)
{
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
    int i;

    i = 0;
    *line = malloc(sizeof(char *) * BUFF_SIZE);
    read(fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
    while (buffer[i] != '\n')
    {
    if(!(*line[i] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char))))
        return (0);
        *line[i] = buffer[i];
        i++;
    }
    write(1, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
    printf("%s", *line);
    return (0);
}

int main()
{
    int fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) // did the file open?
        return 0;
    char *line;
    line = 0;
    get_next_line(fd, &line);
}
```

Comment: so have some int = read... and pass that to memcpy

Comment: `*line = malloc(sizeof(char *) * BUFF_SIZE);` --> `*line = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFF_SIZE);`

Comment: @yano segfault (fifteen chars ugh)

Comment: no line is just  one string, ex "hello franklin"

Comment: "Pointer to Pointer in my function, but it's not a 2d Array" - Of course it is not a 2D array! There is a reason a pointer is called "pointer", not "array": they are different types.

Comment: well yeah I know, but just wanted to make sure people understand what i mean

Comment: @yano: `sizeof(char)` is useless, as much as stating `1 + 1 = 2` for natural numbers. Both are part of the definition of the operand.

Comment: @franklinexpress: So you know it also is not a `char []`, which is used in C as a "string". Theny it is not cler what your want. See [ask], provide a [mcve].

Comment: `if(!(*line[i] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char))))
        return (0);
        *line[i] = buffer[i];` : -->  `(*line)[i] = buffer[i];` and need null-terminator.

Comment: You should only be `malloc`ing once for a `char *line;` .. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the 2nd `malloc`. `line = malloc(BUFF_SIZE);` (there you go @Olaf) will give you a pointer to BUFF_SIZE `char`s. Store your string in that, no need for anymore `malloc`s

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank You very much, that was it, it works! Can you post as answer so I can mark it? Also, why did that make a difference?

Comment: `*line[i] = (char)malloc(sizeof(char))` doesn't do whatever you think it does.

Answer (score -1):

```
There is an error in a way you are trying to print the string.
```

The *line is a pointer to array of pointers. 
each pointer in that array will store a character element.
The *line will not be able to print your stored string.

```
Hence use the below code to get the expected results:    

int get_next_line(const int fd, char **line)
    {
        char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
        int i;

        i = 0;
        *line = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFF_SIZE);
         if (*line == NULL)
         return 0;        
         read(fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
        while (buffer[i] != '\n')
        {
            *line[i] = buffer[i];
            i++;
        }
        write(1, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
        printf("%s", *line);
        return (0);
    }

int main()
{
    int fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) // did the file open?
        return 0;
    char *line;
    line = 0;
    get_next_line(fd, &line);
}
```